# python program detect faces and insert them in a folder

Tags: python, image, opencv, directory, face-detection

I have created a python program that create a folder and take the name from the user, and then detects face from the camera and takes 30 images of the face.
the problem is that I want the photos to be saved in the newly created file, while the code only saves the images in the given path not in the new folder.
here's the file that I'm working on:

```
import os 
import cv2

cam = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cam.set(3, 640) # set video width
cam.set(4, 480) # set video height

face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('data/haarcascade_frontalface_alt2.xml')

# Directory 
directory = input("\n enter user id end press <return> ==>  ")
#directory = "GeeksforGeeks"

# Parent Directory path 
parent_dir = "C:/Users/User/Desktop/images/"

# Path 
path = os.path.join(parent_dir, directory) 

# Create the directory 
new_path = os.mkdir(path) 
print("Directory '% s' created" % directory) 
print(path)


print("\n [INFO] Initializing face capture. Look the camera and wait ...")
# Initialize individual sampling face count
count = 0

while(True):
    ret, img = cam.read()
   # img = cv2.flip(img, -1) # flip video image vertically
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, scaleFactor=1.5, minNeighbors=5)

    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 2)     
        count += 1

        # Save the captured image into the datasets folder
        cv2.imwrite(str(path) + str(directory) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])

        cv2.imshow('image', img)

    k = cv2.waitKey(100) & 0xff # Press 'ESC' for exiting video
    if k == 27:
        break
    elif count >= 30: # Take 30 images sample and stop video
         break

# Do a bit of cleanup
print("\n [INFO] Exiting Program and cleanup stuff")
cam.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: your wording is a bit confusing. You say "the images in the given path not in the new folder" without a clear indication of what's the difference between the two. A reader can figure it out by reading your code snippet, but it would make it easier for all if you were explicit about what the code is doing wrong (not to mention that it could help you troubleshoot as well).

Answer (score 3):

change this line:

```
cv2.imwrite(str(path) + str(directory) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
```

to this:

```
cv2.imwrite(str(path) + '/' + str(directory) + '.' + str(count) + ".jpg", gray[y:y+h,x:x+w])
```

Comment: thank you a lot the code is working now and it saves the images in the new folder.